# QML Felgo - Pass parameter to previuos page when popping navigationStack (or Stackview)

Tags: qt, qml, felgo

I have a QML (Felgo) application and I would like to pass parameter to the previous page of the stack in navigationStack when popping. I would like to populate "myVar" property of Page2.qml (which is '0' by default) with the value '1' passed from Page3 when I call pop() in the Page3.qml. The example code is shown below. I tried that code but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for all.

main.qml

[image]

Page1.qml

[image]

Page2.qml

[image]

Page3.qml

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created the following code snippet that has the following features:

1. `Main.qml` hosts a `ListModel`
2. `Page1.qml` is able to use the `ListModel` in a `ListView` since it sees because `Page1.qml` was pushed into `Main.qml`'s `StackView` and has inherits access to everything in `Main.qml`
3. `Page2.qml` does nothing except provide navigation to either `Page1.qml` or `Page3.qml`
4. `Page3.qml` provides navigation back to `Page2.qml` as well as emitting a signal to `Main.qml` receives to update the ListModel
5. `Page1.qml`, `Page2.qml` and `Page3.qml` all emit signals which are handled in `Main.qml`
6. SVG graphics are supplied to polish the example

Here's the code snippet:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Page {
    StackView {
        id: stackView
        anchors.fill: parent
        initialItem: comp1
    }
    ListModel {
        id: listModel
    }
    Component {
        id: comp1
        Page1 {
            onGoForward: stackView.push(comp2)
        }
    }
    Component {
        id: comp2
        Page2 {
            onGoBack: stackView.pop()
            onGoForward: stackView.push(comp3)
        }
    }
    Component {
        id: comp3
        Page3 {
            onGoBack: stackView.pop()
            onNewNumber: number => listModel.append( { number } )
        }
    }
}

//Page1.qml
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15

Page {
    signal goForward()
    header: Frame {
        background: Rectangle { color: "#ccc" }
        RowLayout {
            width: parent.width
            AppIconButton {
                icon.source: "shapes-32.svg"
            }
            Text {
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                text: "Page1"
            }
        }
    }
    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: listModel
        delegate: Frame {
            width: ListView.view.width
            Text { text: number }
        }
    }
    footer: Frame {
        background: Rectangle { color: "#ccc" }
        RowLayout {
            width: parent.width
            Button {
                text: qsTr("Go Forward")
                onClicked: goForward()
            }
        }
    }
}

//Page2.qml
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15

Page {
    signal goForward()
    signal goBack()
    header: Frame {
        background: Rectangle { color: "#ccc" }
        RowLayout {
            width: parent.width
            AppIconButton {
                icon.source: "chevron-left-32.svg"
                onClicked: goBack()
            }
            AppIconButton {
                icon.source: "shapes-32.svg"
            }
            Text {
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                text: "Page2"
            }
        }
    }
    footer: Frame {
        background: Rectangle { color: "#ccc" }
        RowLayout {
            width: parent.width
            Button {
                text: qsTr("Go Forward")
                onClicked: goForward()
            }
        }
    }
}

//Page3.qml
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15

Page {
    signal newNumber(var number)
    signal goBack()
    header: Frame {
        background: Rectangle { color: "#ccc" }
        RowLayout {
            width: parent.width
            AppIconButton {
                icon.source: "chevron-left-32.svg"
                onClicked: goBack()
            }
            AppIconButton {
                icon.source: "shapes-32.svg"
            }
            Text {
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                text: "Page3"
            }
        }
    }
    Text {
        id: resultText
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
    footer: Frame {
        background: Rectangle { color: "#ccc" }
        RowLayout {
            width: parent.width
            Button {
                text: qsTr("New Number")
                onClicked: {
                   let number = Math.random();
                   resultText.text = number;
                   newNumber(number);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

//AppIconButton.qml
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15

Item {
    property alias icon: btn.icon
    Layout.preferredWidth: 32
    Layout.preferredHeight: 32
    clip: true
    signal clicked()
    Button {
        id: btn
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        background: Item { }
        icon.width: parent.width
        icon.height: parent.height
        onClicked: parent.clicked()
    }
}

//shapes-32.svg
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32"><path d="M8.45 18.367l-.564.855A8.795 8.795 0 1 1 18.832 7h-1.143A7.795 7.795 0 1 0 8.45 18.367zM14 8v6.429l1 1.53V9h14v14h-9.399l.654 1H30V8zm8.982 22h-21l10.544-16zm-10.46-14.177L3.838 29h17.295z"/><path fill="none" d="M0 0h32v32H0z"/></svg>

//chevron-left-32.svg
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32"><path d="M18.793 25l-9-9 9-9h1.414l-9 9 9 9z"/><path fill="none" d="M0 0h32v32H0z"/></svg>
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAARE3ic7VdNb9s4EL37VxDai3MQLVKSLbl1gCRAmwBJse0W6ZmRGUkoRaoUbacp%2FN%2BXlGRbH05qF7spipaOFZEz1LyZeTOi0ywXUoH36v0ijT4DDJE%2FSFtr8EJwJQUrKuHgbxJT8G0A9PhHkejzbUpX9dyMdD4FxWZ9u0p4lAhZwPuUsSnIiaRc7bbwVKWEXSmaTUEkshyVonV5vU4LdSPmlHVssM16Q%2FdC7xVcP7qju3umGcYB1NAwQ%2FC34o2QKyKb8GG%2BKJKh2Y1PturrAw3ilkG8x%2BC5NtOyJvLhyVGw3ONhuS1Y7g%2FCekdX7xbZHZVTwMv%2FYHa6SwkkeU75fAi%2BbaRr0Ee6HgxGozIZ8EvGOqw7gIkd4TX5KhaqAKjL0iKNOWEg3kSydiahZG7wv5Eko40w3Gm%2FYykWXAfsA40U4THTch08JrS69VcURVbthBkfxKoy3QnlKp2rZMN1WM5a8rM8v4oEP18oJXhnb5kwLYSFWMiIaqtFQnJa2C6GxTK2Wsrr1uwjfegiMaOCWNbfpwqYkgvaU1N6t7ZWZuUpK02mmersNIBnSz0z9OgWrxn6nsZE0X4%2BGrHcWINLc%2BmHtPK9dmLDvL2474VQPzP5T2a9wv6l%2BCiH1lsBaspaJz1FwS%2BYpj3VQLvMfjpl25LDP6XktsumxfySZRgldCkFtxm9V3uLsZeahqv9vBwP4OX7AD6kD%2Fzu9eS%2BSD3xzVt3uCSybnB%2FKmtvho4H8PKV5R5SWR1r5hgnabFgygh6L91Ip4LKK9568f5CJarPlaCi%2BPMl2n%2BKHoyq7WkU3BCVQEn4XGTDk1f71HdhhAaC3lNt3qu8K7267Ppa6%2B9ks2wWLU7%2BD03D%2FIiqo5NLkVOpvgLCUlKUbJ%2BCO8WhuatObxVlc0nvqZR0XvPWxXullzSNE7UVRyzNGxyvO1BUZaiuy17ODX01hMN4a0aTnZVvjciWBfwc70qFpMZda1TTrUqDVLVC24U6b63uMHitL%2BAhY7yYWYlS%2BXQ0Wq30idSFQsYj7DjOyDQRYM6p5%2BJhZjnA0XHTf9bp61wzE8xn1k0APR%2BgALrjCbOhP%2FZg4PtnAZyEPqiuDkDmE8BAb54kts6x555NStlkq%2BGAxpMeb5AHguUYejhkei%2F03dswQd4SeYkdQjcMGRz7HkCXrnMbPGYBDAMMME5sjBhyoO95Nho%2FZra%2B98Y28iCaTK5djSAAWD9oAnHoP1qj2g%2FT7mYW1782rdIn7Wji4qWLL51SycTh1ARwT3%2F%2Fj8KITKxcgH1mh3YI9DdB0EMeMxPzORLtv0dmku4%3D)

Comment: It works very well but my pages in the real project (not the small example code that I posted) are very complex and I want to let them in a separate file for more readability of the code. Can you show me the alternative solution with the signal on Page3? Thanks for all

Comment: As requested, I have updated the answer to demonstrate the signal on Page3. If you are helped by this answer, show your appreciation with an upvote.